# Are we allowed to choose real variables in elementary number theory problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example,

> dis/prove each of the following statements
>
> 1. If $p$ is prime and $p \mid (a^2 + b^2)$ and $p \mid (c^2 + d^2)$, then $p \mid (a^2 - c^2)$
> 2. If $p$ is prime and $p \mid a$ and $p \mid (a^2 + b^2)$, then $p \mid b$.

In the problems above we are not told explicitly what $a, b, c, d$ are.

Can we let $p = 2, a^2 = 5, b^2 = 3, c^2 = 6, d^2 = 2$ to disprove the first statement? The reason I ask is none of $a, b, c, d$ are integers. If that's permissible, then $a = p = 3$ and $b^2 = 6$ probably disproves the second statement.

Comment: While there are contexts in which we define *prime* beyond the integers, it seems you are making a lot of hay out of not being "told explicitly what $a,b,c,d$ are."  They are variables.  In the context of real numbers there are no primes, so unless you were "told explicitly" that these are variables over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, I don't think it is a reasonable interpretation.  What are you studying?

Comment: I was wondering this because in other problems my textbook explicitly says "assume $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z.$

Comment: Does this textbook ever say "assume $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$?  The tag "elementary-number-theory" suggests you are studying integer arithmetic, and the topic of the question suggests you are studying prime numbers.  As I said, there are no primes in the real numbers.

Comment: If you go on in math, you'll probably learn that by adjoining $\sqrt{5}$ to the integers you get an interesting *integral extension* $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.  But that's a step beyond elementary number theory in the direction of *algebraic number theory*.

Comment: The textbook never assumes $\mathbb R$. So everything must be integers, then.

Comment: No need to go that far, guys. A simple "the author may'be omitted that sentence after many times of writing it" would have been enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. It is assumed that all the numbers are integers; proposition 2 is true.

**Hint:**

1. Let $p=5, a=2, b=4, c=4, d=3$.
2. $p|a \implies p|a\cdot a=a^2 \implies \cdots$

Comment: If $p \mid a^2$ and $p \mid (a^2 + b^2)$, then $p \mid b^2$ and $p \mid b$? I am not too sure about  $p \mid b^2$ part.

Comment: Yes. That's a special case of Euclid's lemma. Check proof 2 here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Lemma_for_Prime_Divisors